# Using python string substitute with an accented key

Tags: python, string, templates, encoding

I can't find a way to use the string Template.(safe_)substitute with an accented character.

Here is an example:

```
from string import Template
d = {'vérité': 'truth'}
msg = 'je veux la ${vérité}'
msg = Template(msg).safe_substitute(**d)
print(msg)
```

This will output `je veux la ${vérité}`

When I replace both `vérité` by `verite` the code works, so I could remove all accents (unidecode in utf-8 for instance), but I'd prefer not to remove all the accents from my text (for clarity and also for collisions).
I've been reading all around and I can't find the answer. Please help!
Thank you very much in advance

Comment: It seems to work fine if you just use python's built-in `format` - `'je veux la ${vérité}'.format(**d)`. You can even remove the `$` symbol, as `format` does not need it.

Answer (score 1):

By default, using arbitrary Unicode strings for `string.Template` substitution placeholders isn't supported. Per [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#template-strings):

> `$identifier` names a substitution placeholder matching a mapping key of `"identifier"` By default, `"identifier"` is **restricted to any case-insensitive ASCII alphanumeric string (including underscores) that starts with an underscore or ASCII letter.**

Emphasis mine.

To alleviate this restriction, you can create your own subclass of `string.Template` that overrides the class attribute `idpattern`, which specifies the regex for detecting valid placeholder identifiers:

```
class MyTemplate(Template):
    # Regular expression describing the pattern for placeholders.
    # Default: (?a:[_a-z][_a-z0-9]*)
    idpattern = "\w+"


d = {'vérité': 'truth'}
msg = 'je veux la ${vérité}'
msg = MyTemplate(msg).safe_substitute(**d)
print(msg)
# outputs "je veux la truth"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your answers.
Compiling those with a few other readings, I came out with this solution that works great!
Many thanks

```
from string import Template
class MyTemplate(Template):
    idpattern = r'([A-zÀ-ú]+)'
d = {'vérité': 'truth'}
msg = 'je veux la ${vérité}'
msg = MyTemplate(msg).safe_substitute(**d)
print(msg)
```